# how to set env if python,pandas are installed in local dir

Tags: python, pandas

If python,numpy,pandas are installed in local dir,how to set env ,so that ,import numpy as np,import pandas as pd can work.

Comment: Did you install them using pip or conda? Downloading them is not enough.

Comment: i have pip it ,but pip are located in my dir, not in /user/local,because i don't have root

Answer (score 0):

If you install in a virtualenv, then activating the virtualenv will take care of that for you. Otherwise, add the dir to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. (How this is done depends on your operating system.)